# Retromigration 4.5 to 3.5 .net framework for c# application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have created an application with Visual Studio 2013 on my own PC with my own Visual Studio. The application is on test phase and I have to send it to my job's one. Problem, why I start the .exe, I have the error

> To run this application, you first must install one of the following
>   versions of the .NET Framework: .NETFramework,Version=v4.5

If I could install the framework, it won't a problem, but the enterprise where I work won't update it. Thay stand in 3.5 SP1.

The main problem concern the `DataGridColumnHeader`, `DataGridTextColumn` and all their dependencies like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DonneesBrutes" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ResultatCollectionGrande}" Margin="10,60,0,5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" MouseDown="Impacts">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="PrisEnCompte" Width="50" Header="PEC">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Height="20" Width="20" Source="{Binding Path=Flag, Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="PMRQ" Width="80" Binding="{Binding Path=Pmid}" Header="PMID"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Ligne" Width="40" Binding="{Binding Path=Ligne}" Header="Ligne" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LibellePMRQ" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=LibellePmrq}" Header="Libellé PMRQ">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
        Value="{Binding LibellePmrq}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="OTM" Width="80" Binding="{Binding Path=Otm}" Header="OTM"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TOTM" Width="45" Binding="{Binding Path=Totm}" Header="TOTM"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LibelleTOTM" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=LibelleTotm}" Header="Libellé TOTM">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
        Value="{Binding LibelleTotm}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="GA" Width="65" Binding="{Binding Path=GroupeAlerte}" Header="GA"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Discipline" Width="65" Binding="{Binding Path=Discipline}" Header="Discipline"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DisciplineSubstituee" Width="120" Binding="{Binding Path=DisciplineSubstituee}" Header="Discipline Substituée">
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Remarque" Width="70" Binding="{Binding Path=.Remarque}" Header="Remarque"></DataGridTextColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I have seen it's because DataGrid did not exist on 3.5 SP1

What can I do to continue getting a similar result than before?

Thanks in advance for your help, now that I'm not that used to code on c#, If I have some framework compatibility problems, I'm quite lost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have built something like this:

```
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="gridView">
                    <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="PEC" x:Name="PrisEnCompte" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Flag, Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter}}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="80" Header="PMID" x:Name="PMRQ" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Pmid}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="40" Header="Ligne" x:Name="Ligne" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Ligne}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="250" Header="Libellé PMRQ" x:Name="LibellePMRQ" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LibellePmrq}">
                        <GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}}">
                                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding LibellePmrq}"></Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="80" Header="OTM" x:Name="OTM" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Otm}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="45" Header="TOTM" x:Name="TOTM" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Totm}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="250" Header="Libellé TOTM" x:Name="LibelleTOTM" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LibelleTotm}">
                        <GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}}">
                                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding LibelleTotm}"></Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="65" Header="GA" x:Name="GA" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=GroupeAlerte}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="65" Header="Discipline" x:Name="Discipline" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Discipline}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Discipline Substituée" x:Name="DisciplineSubstituee" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DisciplineSubstituee}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="Remarque" x:Name="Remarque" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Remarque}"/>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I cannot test if it works because I have more or less 30 others errors and 40 Warnings. Mainly about Entity Framework for the warnings and missing assemblies/references for the errors... But I think it should work like this.