# Compatibility Entity Framework by downgrading /net framework 4.5 to 3.5

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, .net-3.5, .net-4.5

I have created an application with Visual Studio 2013 on my own pc with my own Visual Studio. The application is on test phase and I have to send it to my job's one. Problem, why I start the .exe, I have the error To run this application, you first must install one of the following versions of the .NET Framework: .NETFramework,Version=v4.5

If I could install the framework, it won't a problem, but the enterprise where I work won't update it. Thay stand in 3.5 SP1.

I have (I think), succeeded to solve my first problem about DataGrid ([Retromigration 4.5 to 3.5 .net framework for c# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295240/retromigration-4-5-to-3-5-net-framework-for-c-sharp-application))

but now, I have lot of warnings and errors, more or less all about the same thing, Entity Framework.

This is 3 of them:

```
Warning 56  The primary reference "EntityFramework" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "3.5.0.0" in the current target framework.  WpfApplication3
Warning 71  The primary reference "EntityFramework" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "Accessibility, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.  WpfApplication3
Warning 40  The primary reference "EntityFramework" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework. WpfApplication3
```

etc etc etc.

I know Entity Framework already exist in 3.5, so how can I do to make it working again?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Finally a simply `Update-Package –reinstall EntityFramework` was enough. on the Console Package Console Manager was enough.

Now I only have the 30 errors. I progress, step by step.